# Using backend service providers with standalone applications

Tags: java, c#, android, firebase, backend

I am developing a restaurant POS & ordering system for my college project, I'm hoping to develop a standalone Java/C# (Still deciding) app which would serve as the POS and adding menu items + an android app for waiters to take orders from customers.

I'd like to connect these two apps and for the backend I'm looking into integrating Firebase or back4app since parse is being discontinued, is this a good choice?

I'd like some pointers on how to set up the database connection with a internet based backend service provider like Firebase or back4app with a standalone application.

Please feel free to suggest other possible routes I could take to connect these two apps together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase realtime database component includes a JAVA Server SDK and a REST API which could be used for integrating with your standalone application.

There is some JAVA SDK documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start